# Import XML from Web Service into XML?

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap

i'm working with joomla 3.1 site, php 5.3.27. i have data stored in a ms sql server 2008 r2 database that's ported out via a wsdl soap web service.

in the xml from the web service, there's a listing of "services", each with "serviceid" and "servicename" nodes that i need to extract.

```
<services count="9">
   <service>
      <serviceid>1</serviceid>
      <servicename>Training</servicename>
      ... and some other nodes ...
   </service>
   <service>
      <serviceid>2</serviceid>
      <servicename>Faculty/Staff Email</servicename>
      ... and some other nodes ...
   </service>
</services>
```

these serviceids and servicenames need to make their way into the default.xml file for the view in my mvc structure. right now the values are hard-coded.

```
<metadata>
<layout title="Service" option="service">
    <help
        key = "Display a service from the catalog"
    />
    <message>
        Display a service from the catalog
    </message>
</layout>

<!-- Add fields to the request variables for the layout. -->
<fields name="request">
    <fieldset name="request"
        addfieldpath="/administrator/components/com_content/models/fields">

        <field name="id" type="modal_article"
            label="COM_CONTENT_FIELD_SELECT_ARTICLE_LABEL"
            required="true"
            edit="true"
            clear="false"
            description="COM_CONTENT_FIELD_SELECT_ARTICLE_DESC"
            default="36"
        />
        <field name="serviceID" type="list"
            label="Service ID"
            required="true"
            edit="true"
            clear="false"
            description="The service to display"
        >
            <option value="1">Training</option>
            <option value="2">Faculty/Staff Email</option>
            <option value="3">Email List Services</option>
            <option value="4">Mass Email Services</option>
            <option value="5">Email Encryption</option>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</fields>
```

and so on...

the part i'm having trouble with is getting it from the soap response into this other xml file. i could create a php doc that could loop through the array and create the option tags, but it seems silly to go from xml to php to xml again, plus i still would have the same issue of trying to import this external data into the right place in this file.

long-time lurker, first time poster, so if i've broken protocol, please excuse and i'll assume the position for my flogging. let me know if i've been unclear or if you need more information. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use XSLT to inject source XML values in the target XML. This is exactly what the XSL language is made for.

This way you keep your template (default.xml in your case) separate from the source values and you can change it without any PHP code.

PHP has many library to process XSLT files, each with their own advantages and problems.